Inconsistent Results When Running Python Mallet/Gibb's Sampling as a Soft-Clustering Method to Identify Optimal Number of Topics
Sorry, but I am inexperienced with Mallet and could use some help. I am currently trying to use Mallet as a soft-clustering technique to assign group membership for a given set of terms contained across a large number of very short documents. I hope to use the resulting group assignments to count/measure the frequency of terms distributed across each of the respective grouped topics. There is no pre-existing typology or taxonomy for these assignments. Because of that, I want to identify a optimal group solution (through the returned coherence scores) and be able to replicate the result with the Mallet code.
So far, I have attempted to use seed values which creates an exact and specific result, but when I run without a seed the results tend to vary between a few different results and it makes it difficult to argue why one specific result may be better than another, which is why I would like to have the code consistently return a single answer regardless of which seed it is running.
I have also added the num-icm-iterations parameter, as was mentioned in another thread. It seems like it narrowed down the results a fair amount to the point where the results tend to lean between one of two different solutions, but I would really like to narrow it down even more if possible.
My current code looks like this:
def run_mallet_and_compute_coherence(dictionary, corpus, texts, mallet_path, temp_dir_path, start, limit, step):
    # Paths for Mallet output.
    corpus_file_path = f"{temp_dir_path}/corpus.mallet"
    output_file_path = f"{temp_dir_path}/topic_keys.txt"
    doc_topic_dist_path = f"{temp_dir_path}/doc_topics.txt"
    output_state_path = f"{temp_dir_path}/state.gz"

    # Ensure that the corpus file is created once.
    if not os.path.isfile(corpus_file_path):
        print("Importing corpus to Mallet format...")
        subprocess.run([
            mallet_path, 'import-file',
            '--input', input_file_path,
            '--output', corpus_file_path,
            '--keep-sequence', 'TRUE',
            '--remove-stopwords', 'TRUE'
        ])

    for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
        # Clean up previous output files.
        if os.path.isfile(output_file_path):
            os.remove(output_file_path)
        if os.path.isfile(doc_topic_dist_path):
            os.remove(doc_topic_dist_path)
        if os.path.isfile(output_state_path):
            os.remove(output_state_path)

        # Run Mallet from the command line.
        subprocess.run([
            mallet_path, 'train-topics',
            '--input', corpus_file_path,
            '--num-topics', str(num_topics),
            '--output-topic-keys', output_file_path,
            '--output-doc-topics', doc_topic_dist_path,
            '--output-state', output_state_path,
            '--num-threads', '1',
            '--alpha', 'auto',
            '--beta', 'auto',
            '--eta', 'auto',
            '--num-icm-iterations', '100000'
        ])

        # Load the generated model.
        ldamallet = LdaMallet(mallet_path, corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, prefix=temp_dir_path)

        ldaModel = gensim.models.wrappers.ldamallet.malletmodel2ldamodel(ldamallet)
        ldagensim = convertldaMalletToldaGen(ldamallet)
        
        model_list.append(ldagensim)

        # Compute coherence scores.
        coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=ldagensim, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
        coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())
        print(f'Number of topics: {num_topics}, Coherence Value: {coherence_values[-1]}')

    print(" " + u'\u2713' + " Gibbs model done.")
    return model_list, coherence_values

#############################################################################

def convertldaMalletToldaGen(mallet_model):
    model_gensim = LdaModel(
        id2word=mallet_model.id2word, num_topics=mallet_model.num_topics,
        alpha=mallet_model.alpha) 
    model_gensim.state.sstats[...] = mallet_model.wordtopics
    model_gensim.sync_state()
    return model_gensim

print("   LDA models starting...")
print()
print("#   Coherence Value")

model_list = []
coherence_values = []

# Run Mallet for different numbers of topics and compute coherence values.
model_list, coherence_values = run_mallet_and_compute_coherence(dictionary=wordDictionary, 
                                                                corpus=corpus, 
                                                                texts=texts, 
                                                                mallet_path=mallet_path, 
                                                                temp_dir_path=temp_dir_path, 
                                                                start=start, 
                                                                limit=limit, 
                                                                step=step)

Can anyone explain why this code keeps returning different values? I have been unable to find any documentation or articles explaining how to do this. Any help would be appreciated.
I have also provided a sample of the results from five different runs using the code from above. Thank you for any assistance!
Run One:
Number of topics: 6, Coherence Value: 0.39282318211226813*
Number of topics: 7, Coherence Value: 0.3870130112666789
Run Two:
Number of topics: 6, Coherence Value: 0.3779967673187221
Number of topics: 7, Coherence Value: 0.3834180326685324*
Run Three:
Number of topics: 6, Coherence Value: 0.4006949110481259*
Number of topics: 7, Coherence Value: 0.3892613210402246
Run Four:
Number of topics: 6, Coherence Value: 0.3670477953310585
Number of topics: 7, Coherence Value: 0.3911717553304524*
Run Five:
Number of topics: 6, Coherence Value: 0.410671950931132*
Number of topics: 7, Coherence Value: 0.377040568874814


Gibbs sampling is a randomized algorithm that will return slightly different results with each initialization. Think of it as searching the space of possible good solutions. ICM is a way to go from a good state to the best nearby state (not necessarily the best possible), so it tends to be more consistent.
Coherence is a useful part of the picture, but doesn't tell the whole story. I wouldn't recommend using it alone. People sometimes find a combination of coherence (which measures the absence of unlikely combinations of words) with exclusivity (which measures how distinct topics are).
What these results are saying, though, is that -- from the perspective of a topic model evaluated through coherence -- there's no really significant difference between 6 and 7 topics. I would look at the actual topics from a few solutions and see if you can tell what the difference is. There's plenty of tools that are older (LSA, k-means) and newer (fasttext, LLM embeddings) than LDA that can do something like clustering, you may want to apply several of them and see if there's a consensus.
Quantitative methods are powerful and can be useful, but they're ultimately not a substitute for knowing your data. Think of them as suggestive, not as oracles.
